# Can I Create a Second Admin Level User Role?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta, capabilities, user-access

I want to create a second User Role, which has the same priveleges like a Admin User Role.
This way I can use the Adminimize plugin to disable some features there.

I'm trying to have a User Account which can view certain Admin stuff, but not everything.

The limitation I got right now is that with Adminimize, if I disable certain features for the Admin user Role, they also get disabled for me (the real admin).

Or does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin:
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

You can set up a new role and copy all allowed tasks to the new role. In adminimize you can then disable what you need to.

Comment: Hey! Thanks man. I will try this out and let you know how it went!

Comment: Nice! I use this plugin on many sites and it works very well. In case you get stuck creating a new role and copy the privileges just come back and ask!

Comment: I managed to do it the way you've given me. Big thanks for that. I discovered something weird. Trying to fix that right now.

For example: I let the account view pages, but I have a plugin to reorder taxonomies, and I only disable "Taxonomy Order", the weird this is, it shows me Taxonomy order in the menu, and disables something else from the menu. :D

- Oh my bad,t his might have to do with certain settings in User Role Editor plugin, Imma find that out

Comment: BTW, I don't have enough rep to upvote, otherwise I would've upvoted your answer.

Comment: No problem regarding not upvoting - if the answer helped you could maybe flag it as "accepted". When it comes to the privileges it can be like that - try and check what happens ;) Sometimes it's hard to know what exactly the privilege means and what is disabled in detail..

Comment: Yea, it was both plugins interfering with eachother. I've narrowed it down a bit to much in the User Role Editor :D I flagged as accepted!

Comment: Like said, the settings can be a bit tricky - Thanks for accepting :)